# Custom root CA not trusted by Chrome on MacOS even after insertion into the keychain

Tags: macos, google-chrome, bash, ssl, certificate

I create a root CA and a cert using the following script:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

set -e

base_folder="$HOME/.acme-development-certs"
start_dir=$PWD

if test -f "$base_folder/leaf_cert/acme.pem"; then
    echo "ACME development certs already created: skipping CA and cert creation."
    exit 0
fi

mkdir -p $base_folder
cd $base_folder



# create root cert
mkdir -p root_ca/certs root_ca/crl root_ca/newcerts root_ca/private

echo 1000 > root_ca/serial
touch root_ca/index.txt root_ca/index.txt.attr

echo '
[ ca ]
default_ca = CA_default
[ CA_default ]
dir            = root_ca                  # Where everything is kept
certs          = $dir/certs               # Where the issued certs are kept
crl_dir        = $dir/crl                 # Where the issued crl are kept
database       = $dir/index.txt           # database index file.
new_certs_dir  = $dir/newcerts            # default place for new certs.
certificate    = $dir/cacert.pem          # The CA certificate
serial         = $dir/serial              # The current serial number
private_key    = $dir/private/ca.key  # The private key
nameopt        = default_ca
certopt        = default_ca
policy         = policy_match
default_days   = 3650
default_md     = sha512
copy_extensions = copy

[ policy_match ]
countryName            = optional
stateOrProvinceName    = optional
organizationName       = optional
organizationalUnitName = optional
commonName             = supplied
emailAddress           = optional

[req]
utf8 = yes
string_mask = utf8only
x509_extensions = v3_req
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
prompt = no

[req_distinguished_name]
CN = ACME Development Root CA
O = ACME
OU = ACME Engineering

[v3_req]
basicConstraints = critical,CA:TRUE
keyUsage = critical,keyCertSign,cRLSign
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash

' > root_ca/openssl.conf

openssl genrsa -out root_ca/private/ca.key 2048
openssl req -config root_ca/openssl.conf -new -x509 -days 3650 -key root_ca/private/ca.key -sha256 -extensions v3_req -out root_ca/certs/ca.crt
openssl x509 -in root_ca/certs/ca.crt -out root_ca/certs/ca.pem -outform PEM


# create leaf cert
mkdir leaf_cert
echo '
[ req ]Development
default_bits = 2048
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
req_extensions = req_ext
distinguished_name = dn

[ dn ]
CN = ACME
O = ACME
OU = ACME Engineering

[ req_ext ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[ alt_names ]
DNS.1 = acme.com
DNS.2 = *.acme.com
DNS.3 = *.sub.acme.com
DNS.4 = acme2.com
DNS.5 = *.acme2.com
DNS.6 = *.sub.acme2.com
' > leaf_cert/openssl.conf
openssl req -new -keyout leaf_cert/acme.key -out leaf_cert/acme.csr -days 3650 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -config leaf_cert/openssl.conf
openssl ca -batch -config root_ca/openssl.conf -keyfile root_ca/private/ca.key -cert root_ca/certs/ca.crt -out leaf_cert/acme.crt -infiles leaf_cert/acme.csr
openssl x509 -in leaf_cert/acme.crt -out leaf_cert/acme-leaf.pem -outform PEM
cat leaf_cert/acme-leaf.pem root_ca/certs/ca.pem > leaf_cert/acme.pem


# trust new CA at the OS level
sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain $base_folder/root_ca/certs/ca.pem


# serve HTTPS using the new cert
NGINX_PATH="/usr/local/etc/nginx"
cp leaf_cert/acme.pem $NGINX_PATH/star_acme_com.pem
cp leaf_cert/acme.key $NGINX_PATH/star_acme_com.key
sudo brew services restart nginx
```

I tried various combinations of parameters for the two `.cfg` and I also tried to add the cert manually to the keychain but nothing to do:

**Chrome rejects it with:**

> #### This site can’t provide a secure connection
>
> **sub.acme.com** doesn't adhere to security standards.
>
> `ERR_SSL_SERVER_CERT_BAD_FORMAT`

---

Notes:

- Safari and curl are fine with the certificate. Firefox has it's own list of CAs and is okay after I add the root CA `.pem` to the Authorities section of it's internal list.
- Nginx is configured to use the cert `$NGINX_PATH/star_acme_com.key` and it's probably not the issue as it works perfectly with a paid one.
- In Chrome dev tools, in the security tabs, it displays `Certificate - valid and trusted`

---

Output of `openssl x509 -noout -text -in <cert>`

- for the cert

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Serial Number: 4096 (0x1000)
    Signature Algorithm: sha512WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN=ACME Development Root CA, O=ACME, OU=ACME Engineering
        Validity
            Not Before: Jun  7 10:16:14 2019 GMT
            Not After : Jun  4 10:16:14 2029 GMT
        Subject: O=ACME, OU=ACME Engineering, CN=ACME
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    ***
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Key Usage: 
                Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:acme.com, DNS:*.acme.com, DNS:*.sub.acme.com, DNS:acme2.com, DNS:*.acme2.com, DNS:*.sub.acme2.com
    Signature Algorithm: sha512WithRSAEncryption
         ***
```

- for the root CA

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 11358523417566447898 (0x9da194de4501091a)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN=ACME Development Root CA, O=ACME, OU=ACME Engineering
        Validity
            Not Before: Jun  7 10:16:13 2019 GMT
            Not After : Jun  4 10:16:13 2029 GMT
        Subject: CN=ACME Development Root CA, O=ACME, OU=ACME Engineering
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    ***
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                1F:50:BB:C9:85:C4:DB:71:46:E3:0E:B4:B5:48:B4:CF:10:C2:27:54
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         ***
```

Comment: Instead of showing us how you generated the certificate, it would be much better to show the actual certs.  Use `openssl x509 -noout -text -in <certfile>` to get a dump of its contents and paste into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Also you need to check your certificate at Keychain Access.
Double click your certificate and in popup under "Trust" section set "Alway Trust"

Comment: I think the command `sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain $base_folder/root_ca/certs/ca.pem` already set every entries to Always trust.

I also tried to add the certificate manually with the Always Trust and it didn't solve the issue.